# Reading documents CSS in Chrome Extension

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to read the pages CSS using a chrome extension. This is what i have in my content script :

```
   var allSheets = document.styleSheets;
     for (var i = 0; i < allSheets.length; ++i) {
      var sheet = allSheets[i];
          var src = sheet.href;
      var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;
     }
```

For some reason the rules are always empty. I do get all the CSS files used in the 'src' variable. But the rules always come as null.. Its working when I try it as a separate javascript on a HTML page. But fails when I put it up in the content script of my chrome extension. Can somebody lemme know why?

Comment: I have tested your code in Developer Toolbar and as I can see "cssRules" and "rules" property are always null. More important - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: read all CSS and parse them and work on the CSS attributes..

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic, but do you have your "matches" set properly? Can you set it to '*' and see what happens?

Comment: oh.. got it.. Ya.. have that set to :      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

Comment: I got the problem too. current I have no idea but use an xmlhttprequest to load it again and retrieve the response text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well thats the Why, but for fun and interest (never done anything with style sheets before) I thought Id do a How....
**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Get all css rules in stylesheets",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js" : ["myscript.js"],
            "run_at":"document_end"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "version":"1.0"
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
// Create the div we use for communication
 var comDiv = document.createElement('div');
 comDiv.setAttribute("id", "myCustomEventDiv");
 document.body.appendChild(comDiv);

// Utitlity function to insert some js into the page, execute it and then remove it
function exec(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script); // run the script
    document.body.removeChild(script); // clean up
}


// function that gets inserted into the page
// iterates through all style sheets and collects their rules
// then sticks them in the comDiv and dispatchs the event that the content script listens for
getCSS=function (){
   var rules = '';

   // Create the event that the content script listens for
   var customEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
   customEvent.initEvent('myCustomEvent', true, true);

   var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('myCustomEventDiv');
   var rules ='';
   var allSheets = document.styleSheets;
   for (var i = 0; i < allSheets.length; ++i) {
      var sheet = allSheets[i];
      for (var z = 0; z <= sheet.cssRules.length-1; z++) {
         rules = rules +'\n'+ sheet.cssRules[z].cssText;
      }
   }
   hiddenDiv.innerText = rules;
   hiddenDiv.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
}

// puts the rules back in the page in a style sheet that the content script can iterate through
// youd probably do most of this in the injected script normally and pass your results back through the comDiv....Im just having fun
document.getElementById('myCustomEventDiv').addEventListener('myCustomEvent', function() {
   var eventData = document.getElementById('myCustomEventDiv').innerText;
   document.getElementById('myCustomEventDiv').innerText='';

   var style = document.createElement('style');
   style.type = 'text/css';
   style.innerText=eventData;
   style = document.head.appendChild(style);
      var sheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1];
      for (var z = 0; z <= sheet.cssRules.length-1; z++) {
         console.log(sheet.cssRules[z].selectorText +' {\n');
         for (var y = 0; y <= sheet.cssRules[z].style.length-1; y++) {
            console.log('  '+sheet.cssRules[z].style[y] + ' : ' + sheet.cssRules[z].style.getPropertyValue(sheet.cssRules[z].style[y])+';\n');
         };
         console.log('}\n');
      };

   // Clean up
   document.head.removeChild(style);
   document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('myCustomEventDiv'));
});

exec(getCSS);
```

In the case of this question Id prolly do most of the checks in the injected script and then pass the results back through the div and its event.  But I wanted to see if I could use the dom methods in the content script to go through the css and this was the only way I could figure to do it.  I dont like the idea of inserting the rules back into the page, but couldnt figure any other way of doing it.

Comment: That is so cool :) .. I did try this, but for some reason, the external CSS are not read. Only the inline ones are. Any idea why ? But love the approach.. Awesome :)

Comment: for internal style sheet, you can access it's content directly.

Comment: for external style sheet, you can't read it's content as security risk.

Answer (score 2):

For getting all external css and all internal css file, you can use devtools API. If you want to use it in chrome extension you need to hook devtool into you chrome extension. This code will work

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
    'my chrome extension',
    'icon.png',
    'index.html',
     function(panel) {
        var initial_resources = {};

        // collect our current resources
        chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.getResources(function(resources) {
            for (var i = 0, c = resources.length; i < c; i++) {
                if (resources[i].type == 'stylesheet') {
                    // use a self invoking function here to make sure the correct
                    // instance of `resource` is used in the callback
                    (function(resource) {
                        resource.getContent(function(content, encoding) {
                            initial_resources[resource.url] = content;
                        });
                    })(resources[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: please check:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools   The chrome.devtools.* API modules are available only to the pages loaded within the DevTools window. Content scripts and other extension pages do not have these APIs. Thus, the APIs are available only through the lifetime of the DevTools window.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but since chrome extensions are Javascript based, they may have cross domain issues. Chrome sets the rules and cssRules to null when programmatically trying to get a stylesheet from another domain.

Comment: Not really, it's a security risk. What are you trying to accomplish by reading the rules?

Comment: I am trying to read all CSS attributes and do some read-only stuff with the attributes. So your saying there is no way to do this on the chrome plugin ? ;'(

Comment: If you have control over the servers that your extension is communicating with then it's possible. Otherwise, short of iterating through the objects in the DOM and calculating their styles, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Chrome allows you access to the DOM in page scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is late, but I think I can help. One method of accessing the cssRules of external sheets protected by CORs is to use Yahoo's YQL service. I've incorporated it into a developer tools extension for Chrome for capturing styles and markup for a page fragment. The extension is in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css%20html/pbgafccggboemhmcmnmglkgidbiigoeh?hl=en) and is on [Github](https://github.com/ifugu/CSS_Plus_HTML/).

Grab the source from Github and look at the content.js script to see how YQL is used. Basically, you'll make an AJAX call to YQL and it will fetch the CSS for you. You'll need to take the CSS content and either inject it into the page as an embedded style tag or parse the CSS using JavaScript (there are some libraries for that purpose).  If you choose to inject them back into the document, make sure to set the new style blocks to disabled so that you don't screw up the rendering of the page.

The extension itself might be useful to you:

[image: Extension Screenshot]