# How do I switch a CSS file in a user script before the page is rendered?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a user script for Chrome that switches out a specific CSS file for a specific website.

The part about switching out the CSS file against a different one works fine, the problem is that I can't get that to happen before the page is rendered. This leads to a very ugly flickering of the site when first the original layout is rendered and then quickly replaced by the new layout I inserted.

I've used `@run_at document_start` to get my user script to run before the page is rendered, but that doesn't seem to work properly. From what I can see [from the official Chrome documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) this should be supported.

For reference, here is my full script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           name
// @namespace      namespace
// @version        0.1a
// @description    description
// @include        http://example.com/*
// @run_at document_start
// ==/UserScript==


var sheets = document.getElementsByTagName("link");

for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; ++i) {
    if (sheets[i].href.indexOf('all.css') != -1) {
        sheets[i].href = 'http://replacement.com/all.css';
    }
}
```

I investigated a bit further and managed to set a breakpoint in my script (for some reason the script did not appear initially in the Developer Tools). When stopping at the break point at the beginning of my script, the site is already fully loaded with the original theme. So it seems the `@run_at document_start` directive just doesn't work and my script is executed after the page is loaded. Though I can't figure out why this is the case.

Comment: That might be because it takes another async round trip to download the css, which leaves a window of cycles for rendering the document. Why don't you try using dataUri as a potential sync option to present the new css content? (this you have to download and cache beforehand)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem in my case, I've updated my question with some more details. It seems my script is not executed at the right time, for some reason `@run_at document_start` does not work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code at document start and as expected didnt get any sheets.  That was expected as, as the docs say their is no  DOM constructed (so theres not going to be any links).  There is some style sheets which can be seen but they cant be accessed by the content script due to cross domain css or something like that.  You can get at them by injecting some code but that wont be able to get at the css files from another domain on that page ( [Reading documents CSS in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320982/reading-documents-css-in-chrome-extension/9348125#) ).

There is an alternative way to swap css files tho and thats using the onBeforeLoad event....

```
function doBeforeLoad(event){
    if ((event.srcElement.type=="text/css") && (event.srcElement.href.indexOf('all.css') != -1) && ( event.srcElement.href != 'http://replacement.com/all.css')) {
        event.srcElement.href = 'http://replacement.com/all.css';
    }
}

document.addEventListener('beforeload', doBeforeLoad , true);
```

Put that in a content script and run at document start.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Though I also had to create an extension instead of using a user script, getting the user script to load before the page just doesn't seem to work.