# Google Chrome Extension Manipulate DOM of Open or Current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Ok, JavaScript/jQuery I got that, I can work with that to do what I want in general. However what I am trying to do currently is work with the DOM of the open/current tab, and I am wondering if that is possible or is all the work I do with an extension limited to the html I provide it with a "background.html" or equivalent.

For todays attempt at taking a strike at a google extension I want to take images on a page and store them in an array to create a slide show like effect from it via a bar I want to add to the bottom of the page appending it to the existing DOM of the open/current tab. I then want "hide" elements in the DOM til the bar is closed.

So my first question is, is something like this possible, can I manipulate the DOM in such a way and read from it.

Comment: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html look at executeScript

Comment: @Gavriel documentation of extensions is crap. I guess that's why everybody's asking pretty much the same in stackoverflow

Comment: If that was the case in 2012 it's bad. If that's the case in 2016 it's very very bad!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are scripts which run in an environment between a page and the Chrome extension. These scripts are loaded on every page load, and have **full access to the *page*'s DOM**. DOM methods, such as `document.getElementById()` behave as if they were a part of the page.

The global `window` objects (including [`frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frames) and [`HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLIFrameElement)) are the only objects which are not *directly* readable by Content scripts.

Content scripts run on every page as [defined in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest). Specify a [match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) at the `"content_scripts"` section, to define on which pages the content script has to run. Also add this pattern to the `"permissions"` section, to unlock the ability to modify the page's DOM.

*Note*: Only [a few of the `chrome.*` APIs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#content%20scripts), can be used by these scripts (such as [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest) to communicate with the [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)).

---

In a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), the DOM of a page is not directly accessible. You can inject scripts in an arbitrary tab using [`chrome.extension.executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript), but you won't be able to get a **direct** reference to an element. For this purpose, Content scripts are required.

Comment: Another thing content scripts dont have access to on a page is cssRules.

Comment: @PAEz `console.log(document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].selectorText);` shows the same result for Content Scripts and normal pages (`null` is always returned when the style sheet is from a different origin).

Comment: Dam, your right (as per usual;)...Im sure you couldnt once tho and thats why I wrote this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320982/reading-documents-css-in-chrome-extension/9348125#9348125