# What Selector to use for Jsoup

Tags: java, android, parsing, selector, jsoup

I am trying to gain the information from the website in my code below, The website has a table  and in that table is the "Tide" times for a particular area, when I try to use jsoup to get that time it returns allot of data but none of it is the time I want.

How do I select that data?

Code:

```
docTide =
  Jsoup.connect(
     "http://www.tide-forecast.com/locations/Falmouth-England/tides/latest" )
         .timeout(600000).get();
Elements tideTableRows = docTide.select("table.tide tr:eq(1), td:eq(1)");
tideTimes = tideTableRows.text(); 
System.out.println(tideTimes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table with `id="Tide"` is filled in Javascript, JSoup report the static DOM, not the dynamic one. Another way to solve your problem is to use an add-on to your browser to investigate into 'live' DOM feeded by Javascript.

```
<div align="center" class="not_in_print">
<h2>Today's tide times for Falmouth, England</h2>
<table id="tide">
    <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Time now:</th>
    <th>Next HIGH tide</th>
    <th>Next LOW tide</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Local time</th>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="localtime" id="localtime"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="hightime" id="hightime"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="lowtime" id="lowtime"/></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Countdown</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="highcountdown" id="highcountdown"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="lowcountdown" id="lowcountdown"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Resources:

- [chrome-developer-tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)
- [google-chrome-extension-manipulate-dom-of-open-or-current-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066100/google-chrome-extension-manipulate-dom-of-open-or-current-tab)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I had wondered whether it was because the table was being updated, being new to programming I was unsure. As Jsoup cant be used, you mention an "add on" for the browser to investigate the feed, would this need to be done each time I access the webpage? as this is intended as a android app so would there be a library available and do you know of any tutorials on this subject? It is starting to sound like it would be better to just access a static table for the Times, but I do like a challenge. Thanks

Comment: Post updated with links (Google about words Chrome add-on extension DOM)