# jQuery keydown trigger not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have this script running at the end of the document loading:

```
$(function () {
    $("input").keydown();   
});
```

The script is in a chrome-extension that run on each page the user loads and doesn't work (i.e. on twitter website). 
However, if the same script is executed on the chrome javascript console it work perfectly.

Do you have any clue about how to trigger this event from the script?

Comment: does you call it from content.js ?

Comment: Well, I have a file called search.js and I put the name of the file on the manifest file to run at document end. The link and the file work fine and if I put some other function inside the $(function(){}); they work perfectly. Also the jQuery script (1.10.2) is called on document end before the search.js script

Comment: DOM can be manipulated only from content scripts, did you put search.js in to content scripts in manifest ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066100/google-chrome-extension-manipulate-dom-of-open-or-current-tab

Comment: Yes, the script works fine. I also have other scripts inside the function I wrote that add elements to the page and they are correctly inserted. The problem is only when trying to triggering a keydown.

Comment: Found this hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152932/chrome-extension-how-to-send-keydown-event-to-pages-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code adding this line and now the keydown even is triggered correctly

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
document.querySelector('[id="inputid"]').dispatchEvent(event);
```