# jQuery.ajax() to grab a stringified version of a CSS File throws CORS error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, cors

On my page, I load a css file from a CDN using a line like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudfare.com/whatever.css?abcdefg">
```

and the CSS loads great.  After the page load, I have a javascript script that loops through all the linked stylesheets and tries to grab their contents **as a string**.  So, using jQuery ajax, the code looks like:

```
//"links" is simply an array of all the linked stylesheets; each value is that link's href
$.each(links, function(i, v) {
   //Assume the first value in the loops is "//cdnjs.cloudfare.com/whatever.css?abcdefg"
    $.ajax(v, {
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        dataType: 'text',
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        }
    })
}
```

I get back the following CORS error in my console:

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load //cdnjs.cloudfare.com/whatever.css?abcdefg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access"
```

How is that possible?  If the file was missing the CORS header, wouldn't it have been blocked when I tried to load the CSS as well?  How did the first cal work fine, but now the CORS is failing?  Is there anyway to load this CSS file as a text file without the server's cooperation?

Answer (score 1):

Loading a CSS file into your page to be used as CSS via the `link` element is different to requesting it with XHR and trying to read its content.

CORS rightfully blocked you from doing that.

You can, however, get a parsed list of rules using JavaScript (I think Firefox can be picky at what it blocks though).

Start with the [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets) value.

Comment: Sadly, the browser I'm working in (Chrome) won't allow that; the linker stylesheet rules are opaque using the document.styleSheets property.  Is there anyway to grab the text of the CSS file using XHR, or am I just SOL on this one?

Oh, and nice name.  That's like a 1-letter twitter handle.

Comment: @AlexZ I'm pretty sure you can have duplicate names on Stack Overflow, so it's nothing special :) I have had trouble trying to get raw CSS data, especially if it's hosted on a CDN outside of your control. Last time I had to use the data provided to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the file via $.get instead:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
 alert( data );
```

});

Comment: Same result - I was hoping that I could get around the CORS restriction using jQuery .ajax, but I guess not.

Comment: `$.get()` is just *sugar* for `$.ajax()`, which all goes through XHR in the end (well, except for ancient IEs).

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320982/reading-documents-css-in-chrome-extension